# need clarification on a binomial distribution question

Tags: probability

Two team a and b play a best of nine series against each other. the probability that team B wins a game is 70% and dose not change over the course of the series. Calculate the probability of..
Team A wins the the series in six or less games

the solution is  $$P(≤6) = P(5)+P(6) = \binom 40 \times .3^5\times .7^0 + \binom 51 \times.3^5\times .7^1 = 1.1\%$$

i tired to figure it out but its not a direct use of the binomial distribution law

HELP. Thanks

Comment: What is the probability that $A$ wins the series on game $5$?  What is the probability that $A$ wins the series on game $6$?

Comment: Well...in order for $A$ to win the series, $A$ needs to win $5$ games...thus, as far as your question goes, the only relevant cases are $A$ wins the first five games or $A$ wins four out of the first five games and $A$ wins the sixth.

Comment: Edited, Sorry @lulu

Comment: i need to know where the numbers 4,0 in 4C0 came from ? also 5,1 in 5C1 @lulu

Comment: So, answer my questions.  What is the probability that $A$ wins the first $5$ games?

Comment: P(x=5) = 9C5.(0.3)^5.(0.7)^4  ? @lulu

Comment: Why would you think that?  That's the probability that $A$ wins exactly five of the nine games...an entirely unrelated question.  My question is a lot easier than that.  What is the probability that $A$ wins the first game?  the first two games?

Comment: probability of wining for team A is 30% so 0.3 @lulu

Comment: Yes, that's right for the first game.  What about the first two?  The first three?

Comment: well, the same for all matches 0.3 since "B wins a game is 70% and dose not change over the course of the series" @lulu

Comment: I didn't ask for the probability that $A$ wins the second game, I asked for the probability that $A$ wins BOTH of the first two games.

Comment: 0.3+0.3=0.6 @lulu

Comment: So, you believe that the probability that $A$ wins all of the first four games is $.3+.3+.3+.3=1.2$?

Comment: well, yeah @lulu

Comment: Probabilities can not exceed $1$.  The probability that $A$ wins the first two games can not be greater than the probability that $A$ wins the first game.  I think you need to review the basic rules of probability.

Comment: i dont have time, my exam is tomorrow and this question is on the exam, the same question but different values, @lulu

Comment: Reviewing the basic rules will save you time.  I don't want to just write out answers, but I will say that I don't really understand the $\binom 40$ term in the official solution.  It's harmless, as it equals $1$, but I don't understand what interpretation would lead someone to write it.  The $\binom 51$ makes sense as in that scenario $B$ wins exactly one of the first five games.

Comment: @lulu For team $A$ to win the series with the $n^{\text{th}}$ game, team $B$ must win $n-5$ of the first $n-1$ games, so the probability is $\binom{n-1}{n-5} \cdot 0.3^5\cdot 0.7^{n-5}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Oh, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited] Consider the possibilities:

(1) To win the series in 5 games, A needs to win first 5 games.

W-W-W-W-W

(2) To win the series in 6 games, A needs to win 5 games in first 6 games.

L-W-W-W-W-W

W-L-W-W-W-W

W-W-L-W-W-W

W-W-W-L-W-W

W-W-W-W-L-W

(1) is easy: $(\frac{3}{10})^5$
For (2), notice that each pemutation has 1 lose and 5 wins which is $(\frac{7}{10})(\frac{3}{10})^5$ and there are 5 different permutations. So, $5(\frac{7}{10})(\frac{3}{10})^5$.

In total $(\frac{3}{10})^5+5(\frac{7}{10})(\frac{3}{10})^5$.

The idea is for (1), all first 5 games must be won and for (2), 5 games must be won in 6 games, but the last game must be a WIN to avoid the collision with (1) which reduces the number of cases by 1.

So, the result comes down to $${5 \choose 5}(\frac{3}{10})^5(\frac{7}{10})^0+({6 \choose 5}-1)(\frac{3}{10})^5(\frac{7}{10})^1$$

This is slightly off from binary distribution because the number of games played changes based on the outcomes of games.

Comment: You are answering a different question.  The OP is asking for the probability that $A$ wins either on game $\#5$ or game $\#6$.  You are computing the probability that $A$ wins either five or six games out of nine.

Comment: I don't think what you suggested is the case.

"Calculate the probability of.. Team A wins the the series in six or less games"? This asks for what I suggested. Also OP's initials steps show the same thing. I'm pretty sure I understood OP correctly

Comment: Yes...but that isn't what you compute.  Suppose they asked for the probability that $A$ wins in five or fewer games.  Since $A$ needs five to win, that means that $A$ wins in five games exactly.  That's $.3^5$.  Since the series ends when one team wins five games, your interpretation doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Ah ok I got your point. So, we stop the series as soon as one team reaches 5. No surprise this question is downvoted.

Comment: That's the norm.  Of course you could declare that you'll play out all nine games regardless, in which case your formula correctly computes the probability that $A$ wins exactly $5$ or exactly $6$ of the nine.  But the OP has included the official solution and I think it's clear that it does not match this interpretation.

Comment: Alright. You are right with OP's calculations which I hadn't paid enough attention. I will release an edit for that soon.

Comment: If you are so inclined, I expect the OP would appreciate it.

Comment: Many Thanks Alessa

Comment: You are welcome